# Search Algorithm with hierarchy and several filters

Tags: java, algorithm, search

This is my problem.

Say we have a list A of several objects, having each object several fields inside it. I need to search the list for 
a hierarchy of fields. My question is what is the best optimized algorithm to do this.

What I am doing know is:

Loop trough list in search of A, if nothing returns

Loop trough list in search of B, if nothing returns

Loop trough list in search of C.

Etc...

Say C returns something from the search, I then need to apply others filters, call it D and E, if D and E matches, return C.

If it doesn't match (D or E), I'll loop trough the list again in search of F, which can also need to match the same D and E.

Take into account that the list A can change in size, and the filters inside each object to.

My problem is that I'm doing this search to match two objects, and the for each object in the list B I do this search in list A. 
Problem is B can have thousands of entries.
It takes hours in some cases to complete the algorithm.

Sorry for the abstract stuff, and I don't even know if this is the right place to ask this, but any help would be appreciated.

I'm programming in JAVA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you explained it is a bit convoluted at the moment.
I'm sorry if i get it wrong. What I take is:

> My problem is that I'm doing this search to match two objects, and the
>   for each object in the list B I do this search in list A. Problem is B
>   can have thousands of entries. It takes hours in some cases to
>   complete the algorithm.

You have 2 lists and you want to find almost duplicates based on some of the fields of the objects.

The first thing that comes to mind is to create a hash function using the java hashes available that computes for each object a hash that only contains the fields you want to compare. Say you are looking for objects that share fields field_a and field_b but not field_c, then my hash function would look something like `(hash(field_a) * 8) ^ hash(field_b)` or something similar. Now you can use this to build a hash map or a array of lists.

Now to use it you go through the list and add the objects to the hash map. Then you take the second list compute the hashes of your objects and see if you get a match. If the hash matches you need to compare the objects themselves, just in case it was a false match due to a hash collision (these should be rare, but happen).

So now searching for thing in this list is almost constant O(1), (depends on how many result you expect to get, and how expensive the hash computation becomes).

You should be able to compute all the hashes (for all your conditions) in a single pass (will be slightly faster than doing a pas per hash due to memory cache). Looking for a match should be very fast.

Note: If you see to many hash collisions (objects have the same hash but they don't match as you want them to) change the hash function a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the time to write this, useful now doubt, sure will use it in the future, but it doesn't apply for this problem, the filters I talk about it's not just if they are equal, but can be greater or smaller, and I even have filters that have some complexity, whole logic for a few.

What I'm searching is for an algorithm that allows to search the list without having to loop trough every time, some kind mixture of linked list with search trees, if this makes any sense.

Comment: Sounds like your conditions could be like `arbitrary_hash_function(data) = value`. In this case there's nothing that can optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

just do the iteration on all the lists at once, and if you have found the correct match from the list `break` the operation ,so you dont have to
tell the program to go through every loop seperately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already had contemplate that idea, but its a too simplistic view for this problem. I didn't explain the whole search algorithm because it would get to much specific. What I'm looking for is some kind of algorithm that optimize the search with the passed filters. Because it matters if I didn't find anything with the first set of parameters, One loop just won't suffice, not without logic behind, and that would make the search slow because it removes the loops but it's heaver on the checks and logic behind.